# lightbox module and scrollbars

Tags: drupal, scrollbar, lightbox2

I am using the lightbox2 module for drupalCMS's login capabilities. I am getting an annoying scrollbar to the right of the lightbox window in Firefox, IE9 and Chrome etc.... Does anyone know how to get rid of it?